# Laravel 5.4 - Duplicate row inserted

Tags: php, laravel

I have been using Laravel for a couple years and I'm stumped on this one. Using Laravel 5.4 with voyager. I have my own controller outside of the BREAD controller

Form:

```
<form method="POST" action="/admin/invites" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-edit-add">
<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="QgLgj5tG4RfD2CxCsqE2Qn5jcWfwQhsk5THT30vO">
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="name">Business</label>
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Business Name" name="business_id" type="text">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="body">Referral Name</label>
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Referral Name" name="referral_name" type="text">
</div>
</div>
<input class="btn btn-primary width-100 mb-xs" type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

web routes:

```
Route::resource('/admin/invites',  'InviteController');
```

Controller:

```
public function store(Requests\InviteRequest $request)
{
    DB::table('invites')->insert(
        [
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id, 
            'business_id' => $request->business_id,
            'referral_name' => $request->referral_name,
            'url_token' => str_random(16)
        ]
    );
    return redirect('/admin/invites')->with([
                    'message'    => "Successfully Added New",
                    'alert-type' => 'success',
                ]);
}
```

When I submit it creates 2 rows in the database. I don't have duplicate routes or controllers. My Request file is empty. I have an ID in the table that is auto increment with primary index.

Any thoughts or troubleshooting tips?

Comment: have you used eloquent try to use model for this

Comment: @AjayDeepakKumar yes. `Invite::insert...` same result

Comment: try to debug `$request->all()`

Comment: It comes back with the correct array with just one entry

Comment: Do you still get 2 entries if you don't `return redirect()`?

Comment: why are you not validating your inputs and making them unique ? See if you still get same data ...

Comment: @BizzyBob yes, I just tried it

Comment: try to debug it from your `route` for example `Route::post('/admin/invites',  function(){ dd(request()->all()) // save data from here });`

Comment: Can you check from your browser console if your form is generating two requests? Also log your sql queries to check if your app issues two insert request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the main point you are missing here is that Voyager calls its `store()` twice. First, through AJAX to validate the fields and then again by normal form submit to store the BREAD to the database.

Take a look at the default `store()` implementation in Voyager:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
        $slug = $this->getSlug($request);

        $dataType = Voyager::model('DataType')->where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();

        // Check permission
        Voyager::canOrFail('add_'.$dataType->name);

        //Validate fields with ajax
        $val = $this->validateBread($request->all(), $dataType->addRows);

        if ($val->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['errors' => $val->messages()]);
        }

        if (!$request->ajax()) {
            $data = $this->insertUpdateData($request, $slug, $dataType->addRows, new $dataType->model_name());

            return redirect()
                ->route("voyager.{$dataType->slug}.edit", ['id' => $data->id])
                ->with([
                        'message'    => "Successfully Added New {$dataType->display_name_singular}",
                        'alert-type' => 'success',
                    ]);
        }
}
```

Notice the `if (!$request->ajax())` condition, the first AJAX call would bypass that but the second call would get into it and store to the database.

So in short, you have to follow the same structure in your `store()` method. Perform your validations first. Then when it's time to save, put that code into the `if (!$request->ajax())` condition.

Comment: That did it! Might be nice to add this to the documentation

Answer (score 0):

your form has some issues:

```
<label for="name">Business</label>
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Business Name" name="business_id" type="text">
```

change label `for` to `for="business_id`

```
<label for="body">Referral Name</label>
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Referral Name" name="referral_name" 
</div>
```

change label `for` to `for="referral_name`

change your `store` method to this:

```
public function store(Requests\InviteRequest $request) {
      $this->validate($request, array(
        'user_id' => 'required',
        'business_id' => 'required',
        'referral_name' => 'required',
      ));

      DB::table('invites')->insert([
        'user_id' => $request->user_id,
        'business_id' => $request->business_id,
        'referral_name' => $request->referral_name,
        'url_token' => str_random(16),
        // If you don't use timestamp delete these lines below
        'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
      ]);

      return redirect('/admin/invites')->with([
                    'message'    => "Successfully Added New",
                    'alert-type' => 'success',
                ]);

    }
```

see if it works.